# Total vs. year reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, statistics

It is probably not a big concern, but at the use list page http://stackexchange.com/leagues/29/year/tex/2012-01-01?sort=reputationchange my "year reputation" is larger than my "total reputation" (by 1 point). However, with other users it is even larger difference. Where do these "extra points" come from?

```
tohecz
#27 year rank
not previously ranked
5,680 total reputation
5,681 year reputation

Claudio Fiandrino
#41 year rank
not previously ranked 
3,925 total reputation
3,952 year reputation
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The total reputation is your current reputation, while the year reputation is the reputation you have earned/lost this year. Since you started out with a reputation of 1, they differ by one. People who had a prior active account on another SE site start with 101 reputation.

I don't know where the additional 26 difference comes from for Claudio. Maybe a rep recalc is in order for him (some deleted post or something). But only a mod or he himself can trigger a [manual recalc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation).